# jqGrid - inline edit can not save result to database after edit

Tags: php, jquery, jqgrid

I'm new to use jqGrid and there is a problem when I try to use the inline edit feature. Here is my code:
    
    
        
        My First Grid

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/ui.jqgrid.css" />

    <style type="text/css">
        html, body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            font-size: 75%;
        }
    </style>

    <script src="js/jquery-1.5.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(function(){ 
            var lastsel2
            $("#list").jqGrid({                    
                url:'example.php',
                datatype: 'xml',
                mtype: 'GET',
                colNames:['id','name', 'status'],
                colModel :[ 
                    {name:'id', index:'id', width:55}, 
                    {name:'name', index:'name', width:90, editable: true}, 
                    {name:'status', index:'status', width:80, align:'right', editable: true},                         
                ],    

                onSelectRow: function(id){
                    if(appid && appid!==lastsel2){
                        jQuery('#list').restoreRow(lastsel2);
                        jQuery('#list').editRow(id,true);
                        lastsel2=id;
                    }                       
                },
                editurl: "example.php",
                pager: '#pager',
                rowNum:10,
                rowList:[10,20,30],
                sortname: 'appid',
                sortorder: 'desc',
                viewrecords: true,
                gridview: true,
                caption: 'My first grid'
            }); 
        });

    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <table id="list"><tr><td/></tr></table> 
    <div id="pager"></div> 
</body>
```

The problem is it could edit the row when I click it, and also can save temporarily after I press the enter. But when I reload the grid, it still shows the previous data before I eidt, which means it doesn't update the database. I wonder why and how to solve it?

Here is the example.php code:

```
    <?php
include("dbconfig.php");
$page = $_GET['page'];
$limit = $_GET['rows'];
$sidx = $_GET['sidx'];
$sord = $_GET['sord'];

if (!$sidx)
    $sidx = 1;

$db = mysql_connect("$dbhost", "$dbuser", "$dbpassword") or die("Connection Error: " . mysql_error());

mysql_select_db("$database") or die("Error connecting to db.");

$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM app");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);
$count = $row['count'];

if ($count > 0 && $limit > 0) {
    $total_pages = ceil($count / $limit);
} else {
    $total_pages = 0;
}

if ($page > $total_pages)
    $page = $total_pages;

$start = $limit * $page - $limit;

if ($start < 0)
    $start = 0;

$SQL = "SELECT id, name, status FROM app";
$result = mysql_query($SQL) or die("Couldn't execute query." . mysql_error());

header("Content-type: text/xml;charset=utf-8");

$s = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>";
$s .= "<rows>";
$s .= "<page>" . $page . "</page>";
$s .= "<total>" . $total_pages . "</total>";
$s .= "<records>" . $count . "</records>";

// be sure to put text data in CDATA
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $s .= "<row id='" . $row['id'] . "'>";
    $s .= "<cell>" . $row['id'] . "</cell>";
    $s .= "<cell>" . $row['name'] . "</cell>";
    $s .= "<cell>" . $row['status'] . "</cell>";
    $s .= "</row>";
}
$s .= "</rows>";
echo $s;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should change the code

```
onSelectRow: function(id){
    if(appid && appid!==lastsel2){
        jQuery('#list').restoreRow(lastsel2);
        jQuery('#list').editRow(id,true);
        lastsel2=id;
    }                       
}
```

to something like

```
onSelectRow: function (id) {
    if (id && id !== lastsel2){
        jQuery('#list').restoreRow(lastsel2);
        jQuery('#list').editRow(id,true);
        lastsel2 = id;
    }                       
}
```

because currently you use undefined `appid` instead of `id`.

Moreover you should remove trailing comma at the end of `colModel` definition: change `},]` to `}]` and place semicolon after `var lastsel2`.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I did what you said, it still doesn't work. I wonder if the jqgrid will auto update the change to database after data has been edited? If not, do I need to call the saveRow method to make it or else?

Comment: @user878729: `editRow` call `saveRow` intern after the user press "Enter". Probably you have problem *on the server side* under the URL "example.php" (see `editurl` parameter which you use). jqGrid just send the modified data to the URL and the web server (your PHP code under `example.php`) is responsible to saving the modified data in the database.

Comment: I check the example.php and found that I don't have a sql statement to get the data from saveRow, and execute the sql. I guess that is the problem. Could you tell me how am I able to do it? Thanks!

Comment: @user878729: I don't use PHP myself. You can use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) or [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) to see the traffic between the server and the client. I don't know which developer environment you use to debug the PHP code. With Visual Studio I can very easy debug my C# code.

Comment: could you check my php file to see if there is anything wrong? I guess I should add a variable to get data from the saveRow method, but I'm not very sure about it. Thank you!

Comment: @user878729: How I wrote you before I don't use PHP myself, but I can't find in your code fragments with `$oper = $_GET['oper']` and then `if ($oper == 'edit')`, `if ($oper == 'add')`, `if ($oper == 'del')` and so on.

Comment: Thank you for your help! At least I know where goes wrong. I'll try to figure it out.

Comment: @user878729: You are welcome! I hope you will quickly find the solution. [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) or [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) could help you to see which data exactly are send from the jqGrid to the server. I recommend you to invest your time to study at lest one from the tools.

Comment: Hi!I am having the same problem, I am trying to update the database with new records but I cannot commit. Did you manage to work it out?How did you do it?Kindly post the answer.I'm stuck I need help